# How Do I Get When Longpress *Stops* on Google Maps?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I'm using the Google Maps api and I know how to get longpress and click, but I want to know when the user *stops* touching the screen.

If I use a normal "onTouch" method (e.g. by putting a layer over the map), then the api's longpress and click either don't get called (if I consume the event) or do get called but onTouch's "cancelled/up" events never do because the event is never consumed.

Google maps always consumes the event as well, so if I put a layer under the map, then onTouch never gets called.

The api doesn't seem to have any way of knowing when a user stops touching the screen.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Since you're using a layer and I assume you're doing good to overlay the layers. maybe this link can help you [Ground Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay) and [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay)

Answer (score 0):

> putting a layer over the map

If this layer is exactly same size as map and is exactly over map, you can get all events from layer method. Isnt it? Just set OnTouchListener to your layer. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but the problem was that the layer was consuming the onTouch events, which meant the map never got them. But if it didn't consume them, then it would never get an "onUp" or "onCancel" event, only "onDown".